# I am getting some error in JWT token verification because of async-await

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt, passport.js

I am currently learning to make API, so the last part I need to learn is JWT token verification to authorise routes.
My authentication is working fine, but I need to pass the response user's data with it.

The code which I have tried has some bug that I cannot understand, but I think I messed up with async await part.
When I am calling `User.findById(jwt_payload.user._id)` I must get the user's data, currently I am getting null. I am stuck on that part with no clue to solve it.

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const { User } = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = async function(passport){
   let opts = {};
   opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
   opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
   passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, async function(jwt_payload, done){
   //console.log(jwt_payload.user._id);
   const user = await User.findById(jwt_payload.user._id);
   //console.log(user);
   if(user){
        return done(null,user);
    }
    else{
        return done(null,false);
    }
 }));
}
```

I would appreciate if someone helps me understand the part of error I have made